# How to reconstruct a W2 for prior year when no access to payroll system

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

My accountant died in August last year, and his estate executor and I have no way to get into his payroll system.  I know it's overdue, but is there any way to build a W2 for my one employee based on information on the EFTPS website, my state's unemployment or any other source?  (State is Oklahoma, but I was a resident of Texas for all lastyear.)

There were no payrolls last year after he died, as I was out of work due to Covid. This year, I'm on Quickbooks Payroll so all set now.

Comment: Wouldn't most of what you need be on your last paycheck stub or deposit advice?

Comment: You should probably hire a new accountant and ask them this question. Or possibly a tax lawyer.

Comment: @jwh20 That's a good point, I will check

Comment: @Kevin - I am working a with a new bookkeeper, but she didn't have any experience with this either.

Comment: @jwh20 - The stub had current pay period only, not cumulative numbers. I will see if I can gather all the stubs and add them up.

Answer (score 1):

Because handwritten W-2's seem to be [not allowed](https://www.patriotsoftware.com/blog/payroll/avoid-these-common-errors-on-the-w-2-form/), try to enter the information in Quickbooks Payroll. Then try to generate a W-2 from that information.

Also see this Reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tax/comments/ahtcbb/handwritten_w2_and_w3_are_not_acceptable/) on generating just one W-2. The consensus view is to use software or an online service provider.

Your late penalty will be substantial: [$260](https://web.blockadvisors.com/w-2s-due-year-1099s/)

Comment: Thanks, you raise a future question of how to actually print or send it.  The first job is how to collect the data, when I don't have access to my accountant's Payroll system.  I have to reverse engineer from my paychecks, stubbs (which are incomplete), and what he actually paid (will look at my check register). 

I think I'm going to need a formula to take what was paid, and my pay check nets, and recompute what the deductions were.

Comment: Right, and your check register or bank statements might have payments to a payroll service, each of which would have to be decomposed into: Net pay, deductions including employee FICA and income taxes, employer FICA (not shown on the paystub), and payroll service fees (not shown on the paystub).